# Hashbang defaulting in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing, hashbang

Do the newest versions of angular/angular-route 1.6.1 use hashbang by default? Take this piece of code for example, I have to use #! when linking to partials because #/ or #/partial2 does not work. I thought that you'd have to set a hash prefix but it looks like it's defaulting to that behavior:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"</script>

  <script>

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/view1.html',
        })
        .when('/partial2',{
            templateUrl: 'partials/view2.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });

    myApp.controller('view1Controller', function ($scope) {
      $scope.sports = ['golf', 'basketball', 'hockey', 'tennis',    'football'];
    });
    myApp.controller('view2Controller', function ($scope) {
      $scope.message = 'We are using another controller';
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app='myApp'>
    <a href="#!/">Partial 1</a> | <a href="#!/partial2">Partial 2</a>
    <div ng-view="">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); inside config to handle disable and enable hashbang as true/false

Comment: @VinodLouis is right. html5Mode will take care of the hashBang

Comment: @VinodLouis Thanks, I know that's true. But I recall hashbang having to be enabled via html5Mode(true) but as it is, without html5Mode(true), it is already enabled. Just wondering when that happened to become the default.

Answer (score 2):

Starting angular 1.6.0, #!/ becomes defaults in routes. I basically worked down versions until #/ worked, which was 1.5.11.